# How to install restcomm on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, sip, restcomm

I want to install `restcomm` on tomcat7, but when I executed the command `ant -buildfile ./build.xml`, I receive the following error message:

```
 "[exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] Reactor Summary:
 [exec] [INFO] 
 [exec] [INFO] Restcomm Sip Servlets .............................. FAILURE [  0.910 s]
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Specification Implementation .......... SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Mobicents Sip Servlets Client ...................... SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets JRuby Integration ..................... SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Specific Annotations .................. SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Core API .............................. SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Implementation ........................ SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Default Application Router ............ SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Catalina 7 Abstract Layer ............. SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] Sip Servlets Loading Specifics for Tomcat 7 ........ SKIPPED
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] Total time: 3.153 s
 [exec] [INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-20T19:30:54+08:00
 [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 20M/309M
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.0:create (default-cli) on project sip-servlets-bootstrap: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository :
 [exec] [ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command. UnsupportedOperationException
 [exec] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [exec] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [exec] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException"
```

Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SCM installed and in your path? It looks like it's trying to get a repo version for your buildnumber plugin and it can't, so it's failing